Not able to notarize electron APP "skipped macOS notarization reason=`notarize` options were unable to be generated"
When I tried to build and notarize my electron app, I get below message
*sudo npm run dist
• signing         file=dist/mac-arm64/Nanoheal.app platform=darwin type=distribution identity=980BE6C48918FDF2EB07A02884B8FB38BC86B2CC provisioningProfile=none
• skipped macOS notarization  reason=notarize options were unable to be generated
• building        target=pkg arch=arm64 file=dist/Nanoheal-4.0.0-0.95.8-arm64.pkg*
Upgraded electron from 22.9.1 to 29.2.0, electron-builder from 22.9.1 to 24.13.3 and electron-notarize 1.0.0 to @electron/notarize 2.2.1.
I upgraded because I was not able to notarize with earlier version I was getting below error.
*Failed to upload app to Apple's notarization servers
# 2024-04-03 09:53:34.262 *** Error: Unable to upload your app for notarization.
*
After getting "skipped macOS notarization  reason=notarize options were unable to be generated" I ran "spctl" command as suggested in one of the help page.
Still my app is not working as before please help me on this case.

AFAIK, if you are using an afterSign hook to notarize it via electron-notarize, then you don't have to worry about this message. Note that the message is from electron-builder and not from electron-notarize. Electron builder is telling you it can't notarize because you didn't provide config options for it. However, electron-notarize will still go ahead to notarize it in the afterSign hook.
